# How to stop cell validation on cancel button click in UltraGrid

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

In my ultragrid, I have a column with Nullable = Disallow, meaning the field cannot be blank. If I try to edit my column to a blank string, my CellDataError event is raised, as I expect. Then however, I want to hit Cancel on my whole dialog (the cell still blank), and this triggers the validation again.

How can I skip validating when the cancel button is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to skip the validation, you have to allow nullable values when the cancel button is clicked and then disallow nullable values again when the cell was updated. Here is how you can achieve it with code.

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ultraGrid1.DataSource = InitializeGridSource();
        this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[0].Nullable = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.Nullable.Disallow;
        this.ultraGrid1.AfterCellUpdate += new CellEventHandler(ultraGrid1_AfterCellUpdate);
        this.Deactivate += new EventHandler(Form1_Deactivate);
    }

    private void ultraGrid1_AfterCellUpdate(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.CellEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ultraGrid1.ActiveCell.Column.Nullable = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.Nullable.Disallow;
    }

    private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.OwnedForms.Length > 0 && this.OwnedForms[0].Text == "Data Error")
        {
            this.OwnedForms[0].FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(Form1_FormClosing);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender as Form).DialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            var activeCell = this.ultraGrid1.ActiveCell;
            activeCell.Column.Nullable = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.Nullable.Automatic;
            activeCell.EditorResolved.ExitEditMode(forceExit: true, applyChanges: true);
            this.ultraGrid1.UpdateData();     
        }
    }

    private DataTable InitializeGridSource(int rows = 7)
    {
        DataTable newTable = new DataTable("Table1");

        newTable.Columns.Add("String Column", typeof(string));

        for (int index = 0; index < rows; index++)
        {
            newTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Text " + index });
        }

        return newTable;
    }
}
```